# Elastic search using aggregations instead of facets

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out how I would do the following query, but instead of using facets use the new aggregation. The reason for my change is then I would like to take it further and instead of just showing 10 tags, show all tags with a count over 0.

```
{
    "query" : { "query_string" : {"query" : "T*"} },
    "facets" : {
      "tags" : { "terms" : {"field" : "tags"} }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: May we know what you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most facet types have an equivalent aggregation type. The equivalent of the `terms` facet type is the [`terms` aggregation type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).

Comment: Thanks figured out part one but was wondering if you know how to show all terms that have count over 0, it only returns 10 back with default settings and I see nothing on that page about how to increase that to over 0

Comment: `terms` facets have a `max_terms` option, so you can control the initial page size. However, there's no way to ask for all the terms in a facet, and there's no way to page through the list of terms. 
I assume (but haven't checked) that using an aggregation instead of a facet will either return all the resulting terms, or allow you to page through them.

Comment: @Avish: setting `max_terms` to `0` would return *all* terms

Comment: Is there a way to force it to return the _entire_ field, instead of individual terms? For example, if you had values like `"Joe Schmoe"`, how do you get the resulting buckets to be "Joe Schmoe" instead of "Joe" and "Schmoe" separately?

Comment: This depends on how ES treats your text field. If it is analyzed, then it will be split to individual terms by words. For strings that should be treated as-is, you want to specify that they are not-analyzed. You can do this in the `mappings`. But this is a different question entirely and if you search for it you'll find many like it here on StackOverflow.